# Text in layer toggler in Leaflet is really faint - why?

Tags: leaflet

I have added a layer toggler using Leaflet and geojson but the text of layer names is too light to see in the toggler - how do I style the text in a darker colour? It's on a wordpress site, if that makes a difference?

I used the usual 
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(map);

[image: faint toggler]

Comment: Don't think it's leaflet configuration, can you send CSS rules about popup text?

Answer (score 1):

Text items in layer menu are embedded in several nested html elements:

[image]

There are many `div` elements that are by themselves harmless, but which have CSS Leaflet classes assigned to them: `leaflet-control-layers`, `leaflet-control`, `leaflet-control-layers-list` and `leaflet-control-layers-base`. Any of those classes can be overriden with font color definition.

Finaly there are three standard html elements: `form`, `label` and `span`. If for any of those elements font is changed globaly via css, it will reflect in menu items.